# How to amend header to include background image - Magento 2.1.7

Tags: magento-2.1.7, less

I have a custom theme on Magento 2.1.7 installation, based on the Blank theme. I am trying to amend the header block to have a background image (behind the logo - though this is not important). I have read a couple of questions and answers and nothing seems to be working.
I have amended my _theme.less file and tried two suggestions:

a)

```
.page-header {
    background-image: url("../images/bog_headerimage.jpg");
}
```

b)

```
.page-header {
    background-image: url('@{baseDir}images/bog_headerimage.png');
}
```

another suggestion was to add the background-image line in the Magento_Theme/css/source/_module.less file, i.e :

```
.page-header {
    .lib-css(background-color, @header__background-color);
    border-bottom: 1px solid @border-color__base;
    margin-bottom: @indent__base;
    background-image: url("../images/bog_headerimage.jpg");
}
```

After each change, I have flushed the cache, I have removed var/view_preprocessed and pub/static files but the image does not appear.

Am I missing some step or doing something wrong? Would be really grateful for any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use image url without double quote.

```
.page-header { 
    background-image: url(../images/bog_headerimage.jpg); 
}
```

Please make sure that your image is in correct folder.

Comment: I have taken the quotes out and checked that the image file is in the correct images folder. Tried again in the _theme.less file and the _module.less files. Still not showing the image. Is there any easy way to test another change to the header so I can check that the LESS file is working?

Comment: please add your less file in `app/design/frontend/Package/theme/web/css/_module.less`

Comment: Hi Abhishek, it's still not working. I'm puzzled as I've followed the steps for creating a custom theme, and have added the .page-header line into the module.less file and the image seems to be in the right location. Im just wondering how I test that Magento is actually picking up my theme, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is any other less file compiling properly ?

Comment: Ive just checked the files in var/view_preprocessed and there seems to be a folder structure for my theme there, but when I look at the _module.less file it doesn't have the .page-header that I added in my theme's less file.

Comment: Ok, I've got it sorted. I added .page-header { 
    background-image: url("../images/bog_headerimage.jpg"); 
} to the _theme.less file in app/design/frontend/Package/theme/web/css/source , cleared the var/view_preprocessed and pub/static directories, flushed cache reloaded my home page and this worked.

Comment: Glad to know that its working now